# Toggle active/inactive of state class using Eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am creating a login page for website and there is a toggle button as a label for a checkbox but, I am unable to toggle active/inactive state of the class by creating an click Eventlisteners using JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let switcher = document.getElementsByClassName('switch')[0];
switcher.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switcher.toggle = 'active';
})
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.switch {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(110,116,143);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.slider{
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

.switch.active {
    background-color: rgb(16,89,255);
}

.switch.active > .slider{
    margin-left: 38px;
}

.remember {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-weight: 500;
}

label[for="remember"]:last-of-type > span {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="remember">
  <label class="switch" for="remember">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
  <label for="remember"><span>KEEP ME SIGNED IN</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle classnames using the element classList property like this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```js
switcher.classList.toggle('active');
```